# Python multiple comparisons style?

Tags: python, coding-style, comparison, readability

I am wondering if there is a way to do the following in a more compact style:

```
if (text == "Text1" or text=="Text2" or text=="Text3" or text=="Text4"):
    do_something()
```

The problem is i have more than just 4 comparisons in the if statement and it's starting to look rather long, ambiguous, and ugly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about this:

```
if text in ( 'Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4' ):
    do_something()
```

I've always found that simple and elegant.

Comment: Usual Python style doesn't put spaces around parentheses.  @Brent had it right, but deleted it for some reason.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you, my code is looking much much better now :)

Comment: @GlennMaynard: Thanks for the pep-8 reminder. Personally, I find it more legible to have the spaces inside parens, but I should remember to leave them out in examples.

Answer (score 7):

The "if text in" answer is good, but you might also think about the re (regular expressions) package if your text strings fit a pattern.
For example, taking your example literally, "Text" followed by a digit would be a simple regular expression.

Here's an example that should work for "Text" followed by a digit.
the \Z matches the end of the string, the \d a digit.

```
if re.match('Text\d\Z', text):
   do_something()
```

Comment: Now that's more like it. ;-) (Actually you don't need the `!= None` part, BTW.)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't need the != None. After years of bouncing from one language to another, I have a habit of over specifying.